# Finding Objects in period / between time X and time Y

Tags: java, datetime, date, grails, groovy

I'm working on a small event calendar in groovy and grails and i want to display only todays events.

```
def getEventsToday(List events) {
List eventsToday;
Date todayEvening = dateDefault(null, null, null, 23, 59, 59);
Date todayMorning = dateDefault(null, null, null, 0, 0, 0);
eventsToday = events.ByStartTimeBetween(todayEvening, todayMorning);
return eventsToday;
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: EventController.dateDefault() is applicable for argument types: (null, null, null, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [null, null, null, 23, 59, 59]
```

I think the dateDefault() Method is missing but i don't know in wich class i could find this method.
Maybe someone knows a possible solution for my use-case / problem?

/edit/
This doesn't work too because today is null:
[Code http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/mracvfus/Bildschirmfoto20110605um11.32.57.png](http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/mracvfus/Bildschirmfoto20110605um11.32.57.png)

Thanks for help!
whitenexx

Comment: Not sure where you got dateDefault from, its not a standard grails method on controllers or anything. You would have to define a dateDefault method/closure on your EventController for it to work (I'm assuming its a convenience method for creating dates). BTW, I recommend using Joda time (there's a grails plugin) for date and time processing, its much less painful than using java.util.Date.

Comment: I got this method from a code example from the internet. The "clearTime()" method from beneath doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `List events` argument contains a collection of objects that have a `Date startTime` property, the following should work:

```
def getEventsToday(List events) {

  Date today = new Date().clearTime()

  events.findAll {event ->
    event.clearTime() == today
  }    
}
```

Comment: This does not work :( It returns the old events list with events from tomorrow.